# Bisection method MATLAB stuck

Tags: algorithm, matlab, binary-search, bisection

I have written this code to implement the bisection method for finding a root of a function:

```
syms x

f(x) = x^3-2*x^2+5*x-10;

k = -10:10;

plot(k,f(k));

a = -2;

b = 2;

c = 0;

while f(c)~=0

    c = a+(b-a/2);

    if f(a)*f(c)<0
    
         b = c;
    end

    if f(b)*f(c)<0
    
         a = c;
    end



end

disp(c);
```

However the programm doesnt stop(it takes too much for it to stop).Do I not implement the bisection method correctly or what is happening?

Here is a picture of the plot of the function from -10:10

[image]

The root is obviously 2 but it cant find it.Help appreciated

Comment: Well, f(2) is zero, so f(0) · f(2) is zero, too. f(0) and f(−2) are both negative, so none of yout conditions are true and a and b remain unchanged. In the loop, you must either reduce the seach interval, decide that you have found a root or decide that there is no root in the interval. (I think you should use a minimum width for the search interval instead of checking f(c) for zero.)

Comment: Also, be careful with comparing strictly to 0, you should use a tolerance interval to avoid problems. (`abs(f(c)) < eps`)